# Multiple replaces with predefined indexes

Tags: javascript, string, replace

This is for JavaScript specifically.

Say I have a string, `"cat dog cat"`, and I must replace both characters 0-2 and 8-10 with `"1"` and characters 4-6 with `"2"`, resulting in `"1 2 1"`.

I *only* know the ranges of what I have to replace - I do not know their content

I know what I have to replace each range with, and I know the ranges to begin with, but if I replace the first range, the positions of everything else has shifted, meaning that any further replacements would affect the wrong indexes.

How would I carry out this replacement correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and iterate over all characters and decide if the character is replaced, deleted or used.

```js
var string ="cat dog cat",
    replace = [{ value: '1', from: 0, to: 2 }, { value: '1', from: 8, to: 10 }, { value: '2', from: 4, to: 6 }],
    result = string.split('').reduce(function (r, a, i) {
        return replace.some(function (b) {
            if (i >= b.from && i <= b.to) {
                if (i === b.from) {
                    r += b.value;
                }
                return true;
            }
        }) ? r : r + a;
    }, '');

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use temporary "stubs"(`null` values) to preserve the initial positions and make the needed insertions using `Array.splice` function:

```
var str = "cat dog cat", chars = str.split(""),
    // predefined ranges (v - replacing value, r - range of positions)
    ranges = [{v: 1, r: [0,2]}, {v: 2, r: [4,6]}, {v: 1, r: [8,10]}];

ranges.forEach(function(o){
    chars.splice(o.r[0], (o.r[1] - o.r[0]) + 1); // removing elements starting from specified index
    chars.splice(o.r[0], 0, o.v, null, null); // filling with stubs
});
chars = chars.filter(function(v){ return v !== null; }).join("");

console.log(chars);  // "1 2 1"
```